# How to add multiple Series (Pandas) together when iterating through a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, series, addition

I am trying to add multiple Series together using a for loop using the =+ function.

On the surface, this gives me the right answer however it gives the answer in str format, so I have problems when I try to graph it.

```
import pandas as pd 

for ID in ID_list:
    Proxy =+ Value_dict[ID].loc[:,'VALUE']
Summed_dict.update({Source:Proxy})
```

Value_dict has a format like this, where each element of the dictionary is a dataframe;

```
Value_dict['a'] 
SETTLEMENTDATE       VALUE   + more unwanted columns
2019/01/01 00:55:00    3
2019/01/01 01:00:00    1
2019/01/01 01:05:00    0
2019/01/01 01:10:00    5
2019/01/01 01:15:00    0
Name: SCADAVALUE, dtype: object

Value_dict['b'] 
SETTLEMENTDATE       VALUE   + more unwanted columns
2019/01/01 00:55:00    1
2019/01/01 01:00:00    0
2019/01/01 01:05:00    1
2019/01/01 01:10:00    0
2019/01/01 01:15:00    4
Name: SCADAVALUE, dtype: object
```

Comment: `Value_dict[ID].loc[:,'VALUE'].astype('int')` perhaps? Also a problem that `Proxy` is undefined.

Comment: I ended up using .astype(float) as some of my data ended up being of that form, I think this is the most straightforward answer so far

Comment: It may be worth considering the effect that misalignment would have on your data. It may be better to do some sort of join and then summation if you can't rely on the index to be identical and identically-ordered between your data frames.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with `concat`

```
newdf = pd.concat(Value_dict).groupby(level=1).VALUE.sum()
```

Comment: How exactly does .VALUE work? is that supposed to just bring out the value column?

Comment: At the moment when I run this code it does the addition for all the columns I have in the dataframe

Comment: @LukaVlaskalic .VALUE only slice the column you want to sum